Brightness of reflected ray as function of distance of medium separation
Consider a light beam in a glass medium. Now, cut the medium in half, perpendicular to the beam and separate the two halves by some distance. Since there is a change in the index of refraction between the media, the light will be reflected off both surfaces. This is conveniently shown in the diagram below from, Optics, 5th Edition by Eugene Hecht:

Hecht then states:
Nonetheless, in practice, it is a thin layer ( $\lambda>2$ deep) of unpaired atomic oscillators near the surface that is effectively responsible for the reflection. For an air–glass interface, about 4% of the energy of an incident beam falling perpendicularly in air on glass will be reflected straight back out by this layer of unpaired scatterers.
... If the two glass regions are made to approach one ­another increasingly closely (so that we can imagine the gap to be a thin film of, say, air—p. 416), the reflected light will ­diminish until it ultimately vanishes as the two faces merge and disappear and the block becomes continuous again. In other words, beam-I cancels beam-II; they must have been 180° out-of-phase.
But if everything is happening due to the discontinuity of the medium and distance within the medium up to $\lambda/2$, then why is the distance between the media relevant? That is, why is brightness of reflection a function of separation distance?
